# Specify which shell NPM scripts run in

Tags: bash, shell, npm

I've run into a pretty dumb and frustrating issue.

My team is using this script quite regularly for development

`cd client && source .env && yarn run start`

They are all on macOS and it works fine. I am on Ubuntu and for some reason NPM sends this command to sh instead of bash (on sh the source command is . ) which throws an error.

I've spent hours trying to figure out how to change that but I can't see anything. Is there some setting I can change? Why does NPM choose sh instead of the much more common bash or zsh? Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: type `echo $SHELL` on your terminal , what do you see ?

Comment: /bin/bash obviously because I'm using bash. NPM proxies all shell commands to sh but I need it to use my current shell instead, that is the issue

Comment: do `npm set shell /bin/bash` . if your bash shell is not in `/bin/` do this `npm set shell ${SHELL}`

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: wtf. do `npm get shell` and see what you get

Comment: {/bin/bash} but when I run npm run dev it throws an error sh: source not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157100/discussion-between-0-sh-and-robbie-milejczak).